# Kafka consumer не читает сообщения из очереди

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Есть 2 сервиса с чтением из очереди по одному топику, конфигурации одинаковые кроме groupId, 1 partition, в логах вижу одинаковую конфигурацию consumer и успешное подключение.
Один сервис читает сообщения из очереди, второй - нет.
Из обнаруженных различий, в рабочем сервисе есть логи

```
Setting offset for partition topic-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=420, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch
```

А во втором таких нет. Пробовал разные auto.offset.reset, не помогает. Реализация работы с kafka в сервисах идентична. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Во втором, возможно, кидается exception при обработке сообщения, из-за этого offset не сдвигается